# Containing hidden "objects" in ListviewItem, with inheritance?

Tags: .net, wpf, inheritance, listviewitem

I have a listview control, and it's data refreshing continously. I'd like to 'put' an XElement into a row, so I if e.g. double-click on the row, the double-click would call a method, with the 'hidden' xelement parameters.

I hope I started to solve it, the debugger doesn't show any errors, but I don't know how to reach the XElement-typo element from the row.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item = listBighit.Items.Add(new Offer (sor[0].ToString(),xml1,xml2));
            item.SubItems.Add(sor[1].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(sor[2].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(sor[3].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(sor[4].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(sor[5].ToString());

public class Offer : ListViewItem
{
    protected XElement _xml1;
    protected XElement _xml2;
    public Offer(string penznem, XElement xml1, XElement xml2)
    {
        this.xmlAddress1 = xml1;
        this.xmlAddress2 = xml2;
        base.Text = penznem;
    }
    public XElement xmlAddress1
    { get { return this._xml1; } set { this._xml1 = value; } }
    public XElement xmlAddress2
    { get { return this._xml2; } set { this._xml2 = value; } } 
}
```

I hope some guru can help me out :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item = listBighit.Items.Add(new Offer (sor[0].ToString(),xml1,xml2));
```

The first line doesn't do anything.  I imagine what you *really* want to do is create an Offer, not a ListViewItem:

```
Offer item = new Offer(...);
item.SubItems.Add(...);
// etc..
listBighit.Items.Add(item);
```

Then when you need to retrieve an item from the ListView, cast it back to an Offer:

```
Offer first = (Offer)listBighit.Items[0];
```